# How to reduce image quality / image size using php, we tried but not able to solve?

Tags: php, mysql, json

Here is a code what I am using to create image reducer but not getting solution

this code taking an image from my chosen path from the computer and uploading as is it, like same image size and same quality, but I want to reduce image size at the same ratio

```
<?php
    include '../database/db.php';
    include "../includes/session.php";

if(isset($_GET["d"]))
    {
        $output_dir=($_GET['d']);
        $directory=($_GET['fp']);
        $pid=($_GET['pid']);
        $lid=($_GET['lid']);
        $subjecta=($_GET['subject']);
    }

if(isset($_FILES["myfile"]))
    {
        $ret = array();

        $error =$_FILES["myfile"]["error"];
        //You need to handle  both cases
        //If Any browser does not support serializing of multiple files using FormData() 
        if(!is_array($_FILES["myfile"]["name"])) //single file
        {
            $fileName = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir.$fileName);

            $ret[]= $fileName;

            $path = "$directory$fileName";  
            $query = "INSERT INTO table_name (lid,pid,nots,filename)VALUES('$lid','$pid','$path','$fileName')";
            $suc= mysql_query($query);
        }else{
            $fileCount = count($_FILES["myfile"]["name"]);
            for($i=0; $i < $fileCount; $i++)
            {
                $fileName = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"][$i];
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"][$i],$output_dir.$fileName);

                $ret[]= $fileName;

                $path = "$directory$fileName";  
                $query = "INSERT INTO table_name (lid,pid,nots,filename)VALUES('$lid','$pid','$path','$fileName')";
                $suc= mysql_query($query);
            }

        }
        echo json_encode($ret);
    }
?>
```

we made this code for a single file and multiple files

Comment: JSON has nothing to do with image size or quality.

Comment: Where's the image processing code ?

Comment: `imagecopyresampled` would seem to be the php function most suited to this

Comment: that is the processing page where image getting save in my drive with the given path

Comment: in which line I have to use imagecopyresampled ?

Comment: A book or tutorial should help

Comment: ok, do you have any link for the tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

you should process the uploaded image on your server using something like ImageMagick, you can read more here http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

you can find some examples of image manipulation here:

http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.examples-1.php